# Are there enough keys for all the chests and cages?

Tags: dust-an-elysian-tail

In *Dust: An Elysian Tail* are there enough keys found throughout the game for all the chests and cages or do I have to buy keys (3,000G) to open all the chests and cages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to buy 4 more keys to open all the chests and cages.

Comment: So it's an extra 12,000G for everything then?

Comment: Yes its a bit tiresome but the last chest I think is worth it :)